# Linking JS and jQuery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery and JS. I'm not quite sure what the error is here, but my JS/jQuery will not run. Could someone review my HTML and let me know what is wrong? Is there another place, like my js file, that I need to input some code to link the pages together? Thank you! :)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>


 <body>
 <div id="clock"></div>


  </body>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>

<script src="time.js"></script>

 </html>
```

Comment: Did you import jquery file? If the code above is all you got, you need to add jquery file to your code.

Comment: Where did you find the code `google.load("jquery", "1.3.2")` ?

Comment: you need to show us what is in `time.js`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
```

And move your stylesheet in `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>

    <script src="time.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
     <div id="clock"></div>  

  </body>   


 </html>
```

Comment: how does he have too many html tags? and as with all the other answers you can have the script tags at the end.

Comment: You can have script tags at the end. I always put them to the front. He had <!DOCTYPE html> then <html> that's not normal. I've never really been able to get it to work with that.

Comment: But as I look it up. I see it being used more than what I remember. I apologize and will remove that part out of my answer.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is a [doctype declaration](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/) it is not an `<html>` tag

Comment: I'll admit when I'm wrong. I'll fix my answer accordingly. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following approach](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) for loading jquery. It is slightly more performant than using the google.load() approach. It isn't a huge gain, but it does cut down on a few unnecessary HTTP requests:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // This is more like it!
      });
</script>
```

EDIT 1: Here is how your file might look:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>

   <body>
       <div id="clock"></div>

       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // Do your initialization here or in a separate js file.
          });
       </script>

       <script src="time.js"></script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: As was already pointed out, <script> tags should be placed at the bottom in order to avoid latency on page load. Stylesheets should be placed in <head>.

Comment: Could you clarify what I need to exactly put in the "Do you initialization here or separate js file" area? Do you mean I can either put all my jQuery code in there? If I keep my jQuery code in a separate file, what exactly would I type there?

Comment: If what you want to do is run some jQuery code within your time.js file when the page loads, then you can easily do that. See this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/4cD44/

Comment: To clarify, simply omit the "Do your initialization..." section and script tags completely and just load everything the way I mentioned in the link provided. So the content in my link would, for example, be what is in your time.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely of causes is your code is not waiting for your jQuery library to load.

Using the google loader will load the library asynchronously, so unless you use the callback feature of the .load call your code in time.js is going to run before jQuery is loaded.

So include time.js before the google.load call and put any code that will need to run right away into a callback function that `.load` can call when it is finished

**time.js**

```
function jQueryReady(){
   //do your ready code here
}
```

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2",{
       callback:jQueryReady
    });
</script>
```

[google.load documentation](https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad)

The other option is to load jquery from a cdn/own server first and not use google.load to load it

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="time.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The DOM is very important when it comes to html and javascript.
The html tag have two main children i.e head and body tags or elements.

Put the javascript tags just before the closing body tag.
or place it within the  the head tag